# Possibly ambiguous boundary conditions for wave equation

Tags: wave-equation

Consider the wave equation

$$u_{tt}=u_{xx}$$
with boundary conditions
$$u\left(x,t\right)=X\left(x\right)T\left(t\right)$$
$$u\left(\pm a,t\right)=0$$
$$u\left(x,0\right)=\max\left(0,1-\left(x/b\right)^2\right)$$
$$u_t\left(x,0\right)=0$$
$$-a\le x\le a$$
Let
$$u\left(x,t\right)=X\left(x\right)T\left(t\right)$$
$$\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}={\frac{T}{T}}^{\prime\prime}=-\lambda$$
$$X(x)=A\cos\sqrt\lambda x+B\sin\sqrt\lambda x$$
$$X\left(-a\right)=A\cos\sqrt\lambda (-a)+B\sin\sqrt\lambda(-a)=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow\sqrt\lambda\left(-a\right)=n\pi$$ with $$A=0$$

Or
$$\sqrt\lambda\left(-a\right)=\frac{n\pi}{2}$$ with $$B=0$$
Which seems slightly ambiguous.
Just wondering whether there is a clue I am not seeing which would allow us to conclude that $$X(0) = 0$$
which would confirm that $$\sqrt\lambda\left(-a\right)=n\pi$$ with $$A\ =0.$$

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ambiguity. The nontrivial solutions to $X(\pm a)=0$, where
$$
X(x)=A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x), \tag{1}
$$
are
\begin{align}
X_n^{(1)}(x)&=A_n\cos\left(\sqrt{\lambda_n^{(1)}}x\right)\qquad
\left(\lambda_n^{(1)}=\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2a}\right)^2,\, n\in\mathbb{N}\right),
\tag{2a} \\
X_n^{(2)}(x)&=B_n\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda_n^{(2)}}x\right)\qquad
\left(\lambda_n^{(2)}=\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}\right)^2,\, n\in\mathbb{N}^*\right).
\tag{2b}
\end{align}
It is, however, possible to rewrite $(2)$ in a more compact way. To do this, first rewrite $X(x)$ as
$$
X(x)=C\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}(x+a))+D\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(x+a)), \tag{3}
$$
which is equivalent to $(1)$. In this representation, the nontrivial solutions to $X(\pm a)=0$ are given by
$$
X_k(x)=D_k\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda_k}(x+a)\right)\qquad\left(\lambda_k=\left(\frac{k\pi}{2a}\right)^2,\,k\in\mathbb{N}^*\right). \tag{4}
$$
These functions are equivalent to $(2\text{a})$ if $k$ is odd, and to $(2\text{b})$ if $k$ is even.